# Upon PhoneGap 2.1 >> 2.2 upgrade, XCode not showing console.log() messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile

1. Starting PhoneGap app in Android, once I like what I see, I rsync www/ to an XCode project and I further test + fine tune over there.
2. I updated to PhoneGap 2.2 and, all of a sudden, I'm not seeing `console.log()` messages in my XCode console.
3. I had a PhoneGap 2.1 application with this exact same HTML/CSS/JS that still runs with current code and outs to the XCode console as expected.
4. Working beautifully in Android w/ the Eclipse console.  `console.log()` message below yields expected behavior.
5. I'm not seeing any errors or misbehvaior of any sort in my XCode console
6. I'm seeing erroneous behavior with the application itself.
7. I use jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 & jQuery 1.7.1 alongside

I'm particularly stuck on this one, any help will be massively appreciated

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function()
{
    console.log("mobile init---------------");
    $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

The PhoneGap boilerplate code that is generated after running ./create contains a DOM element with a "deviceready" class.  Inside of my index.js file, the receivedEvent method was failing silently since I had removed that DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean #3 literally - did you update the javascript component as well? Even if you think you did replace the javascript, the update sometimes doesn't actually make it onto the device.

Could jquery mobile init be firing before phonegap deviceready? With phonegap, console.log is actually similar to a plugin call. Since it is timing related, leaving $.mobile.autoinitializepage on may work most of the time, but if 2.2 deviceready takes slightly longer, you would see something like what you are describing.

Comment: I did update my pointing at `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>` this is very puzzling.